# What is the name of this non linear navigation control?

Tags: navigation

I have seen this control used in a number of apps, but I do not know a formal name for it and any of my attempts to search for it are failing because of a lack of a concise way to describe it. I have seen it used as type of non-linear navigation control, but I suppose it could be linear. Its nodes can indicate a certain status, such as 'Complete'.

[image]

Is there a formal name for this control? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4):

It's a discrete (*separate; distinct; individual*) progress bar, in contrast to the more common continuos (*without break, cessation, or interruption*).

[How to deal with variable number of steps in discrete progress bar?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/how-to-deal-with-variable-number-of-steps-in-discrete-progress-bar)

Comment: Thank you for the link. That was interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's a type of [progress bar](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html) that shows you where you are in the completion of a flow.

Answer (score 0):

It's a flow bar - some applications allow the user to click on the individual steps/nodes but many just use it to indicate the flow of the process (like in a Wizard)