# Website progress tracker

Tags: usability, gui-design, design, progress-bar, process

I’m working on an application that has multiple tasks that need to be completed in sequence (e.g. think placing your order with amazon).  We have a progress bar at the top of the web page which shows which step of the process you are in.

My question is with a unique situation we’ve come across.  For the application in question; the number of steps in the process will vary.  At one point; the user is asked to select an option in a drop down.  Depending on their answer;  they may have 2, 3 or 4 remaining steps.  2 of these steps are always the same.

I was wondering if anyone would have a suggestion as to how to handle this.  I think it would look weird and confusing if the number of steps in the task progress bar starts changing based on the users selection.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Oaryx, welcome to UXSE. Do you need to show the amount of steps still needed? For instance https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/how-to-deal-with-variable-number-of-steps-in-discrete-progress-bar this question also describes a similar (possible duplicate) problem. If you feel that it does not answer your question fully you could perhaps explain why it does not solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Kevin!  Thanks so much for your response.  The question that you identified is exactly what I was asking!  Thank you so much for pointing me there. :)